# constructor for functor class that can accept any callable objects

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, functor

I want to create a functor class that can accept other callable objects.
For example I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class RetType,class ObjType,class... Params>
struct Functor {
    using FuncSig = RetType (ObjType::*)(Params...);
    FuncSig funcptr;
    ObjType *obj;

    RetType operator()(Params... params) {
        return (obj->*funcptr)(params...);
    }
};
class command {
    int x;
    char *ch;
    public:
    void operator()(int a,char *x) {
        // some task
        std::cout << "task1 done!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Functor<void,command,int,char *> f;
    command c;
    f.funcptr = &command::operator();
    f.obj = &c;
    char x[] = {'a','b'};
    f(100,x);
}
```

This works. But when I want to work with normal function callable object, I need to create a different Functor class:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class RetType,class ObjType,class... Params>
struct Functor {
    using FuncSig = RetType (ObjType::*)(Params...);
    FuncSig funcptr;
    ObjType *obj;

    RetType operator()(Params... params) {
        return (obj->*funcptr)(params...);
    }
};
class command {
    int x;
    char *ch;
    public:
    void operator()(int a,char *x) {
        // some task
        std::cout << "task1 done!" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class RetType,class... Params>
struct Functor2 {
    using FuncSig = RetType (*)(Params...);
    FuncSig funcptr;

    RetType operator()(Params... params) {
        return (*funcptr)(params...);
    }
};
void normalFunction(double x) {
    std::cout << "task2 done!" << std::endl;    
}

int main() {
    Functor<void,command,int,char *> f;
    command c;
    f.funcptr = &command::operator();
    f.obj = &c;
    char x[] = {'a','b'};
    f(100,x);

    //........
    Functor2<void,double> g;
    g.funcptr = normalFunction;
    g(1.2);
}
```

How to create a generic Functor class that can accept any callable objects (class with operator() or normal function) with the following acceptable syntax.

```
Functor<ReturnType,int,double,more params ..> F(a_callable_objects);
F(arguments);
```

Comment: Use `std::function`

Answer (score 2):

With [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), you might do:

```
command c;
std::function<void(int, char *)> f = [&](int n, char* buf){ return c(n, buf); };
char x[] = {'a', 'b'};
f(100, x);

//...
std::function<void(double)> g = normalFunction;
g(1.2);
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1694eba79fa2825)

Comment: Hi Jarod42, I have one question, I was reading the "Modern C+ design" book. They talk about functors in depth. Can std::function be used instead of functor class ?

Comment: `std::function` is a functor which take functor. As it type-erase its content, it has some extra cost. It might have "cleaner" interface as it clearly state input/output contrary to regular template.